# Pandas: How to filter on a parameter with both one to many and one to one relationships

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a dataset of several tables.  Some of the fields overlap but on some tables they may have a one to many relationship while on other tables they may have a one to one relationship.  I am trying to create a new dataframe where I can take the values associated with one field (one to one) and the values associated with that same field but in another table (one to many) and have them all listed on the new dataframe (one to many).

One dataframe:

```
         finishtId eventId instanceId  ...       value statusId finishType
0               1     18        1  ...           218.3        1   Positive
1               2     18        2  ...         217.586        1   Positive
2               3     18        3  ...         216.719        1   Positive
3               4     18        4  ...         215.464        1   Positive
4               5     18        5  ...         218.385        1   Negative
```

Another dataframe:

```
      eventId  instanceId red blue     time duration  milliseconds
0        841       153     1    1  17:05:23   26.898         26898
1        841        30     1    1  17:05:52   25.021         25021
2        841        17     1   11  17:20:48   23.426         23426
3        841         4     1   12  17:22:34   23.251         23251
4        841        13     1   13  17:24:10   23.842         23842
5.       841.      153.    2   45. 17:45:30.  24.786.        26473
     ...       ...   ...  ...       ...      ...           ...
7633    1036       822     2   48  16:20:38   22.143         22143
7634    1036         1     2   50  16:23:05   21.853         21853
7635    1036       849     2   49  16:24:00   22.475         22475
7636    1036       154     2   62  16:42:16   24.010         24010
7637    1036       822     3   64  16:42:47   22.607         22607
```

I want to create a new dataframe that appends all of the values from dataframe2 (red, blue, time, duration, milliseconds) to the instanceId and eventId fields so that dataframe1 shows the one to many relationships. Also I want to create a new field that tells me how many many reds per instanceId and eventId (numRed) Basically something like this:

```
          eventId instanceId  red  numRed blue  ...     time  duration   value statusId finishType
0             841    153        1       2   17  ... 17:05:23    26.898   218.3        1   Positive
1             841    153        2       2   52  ... 17:45:30    24.786 217.586        1   Positive
1             841    146        1       1   40  ... 17:32:30    24.986 217.586        1   Negative
```

So essentially every red, blue, time, duration, value, statusId, and finishType is listed for every instanceId for every eventId.  I'm new to Pandas so I've been digging through functions but I keep getting errors usually associated with data type (float vs str) etc...

UPDATE: After getting the solution from Edunne I realized that what I think would work better for the dataset is actually something else.  I'd prefer to instead merge down the rows of 'red' values for each 'instanceId' for each 'eventId'.  The values that are different would be averaged, so the mean of the 'duration' and the mean of the 'value' fields.  Something looking like this:

```
          eventId instanceId  numRed ...  duration   value statusId finishType
0             841    153          2  ...     25.842   218.3        1   Positive
1             841    146          1  ...     24.986 217.586        1   Negative
```

Comment: You should not ask a question, get an answer and then say that you need something else. If the answer is a solution to your problem as originally stated, accept it. Ask a new question about your new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show us what you tried! Makes it easier for people to answer.

Pandas [Merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is how I'd approach it though. Something like:

```
new_df = df2.merge(df1, on=["eventID", "instanceId"], how="outer")
```

The new_df will contain all rows in df2 and any matching rows from df2.

You might run into issue if the datatypes for "eventID" or "instanceId" are different across the two dataframes, but that should be easy enough to address...

**Edit**
Probably looking for [group_by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). You should perform the aggregation on the second dataframe before joining/merging with the other.

```
# Dictionary with keys as column names and values as the aggregation/summary method.
agg_dict = {
    "duration": "mean",
    "value": "mean"
}
group_by_columns = ["eventID", "instanceId"] # We'll get one row in output for each combination of these columns
new_df2 = df2.groupby(group_by_columns).agg(agg_dict).reset_index()

result = new_df2.merge(df1, on=["eventID", "instanceId"], how="outer")
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly what I was looking for.  Only problem is that now that I see the result I'm looking for something else :). So instead of listing every 'red' value for each 'instanceId' for each 'eventId' I want to just keep the 'numRed' value and find the mean of the 'duration', and the mean of the  'value' for those which have more than 1 'red' value.  Essentially merge them down to 1 row.

Comment: This was the result:
SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported

Comment: Can you provide your code for the agg_dict? That's the error you get when you have a column in the agg_dict that doesn't exist in the dataframe

Comment: Sorry it was a typo on my part.  I'm still getting an error but it has to do with the data type:
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

should I do a df2.loc['duration']=float()

Comment: No worries. For changing datatypes I would go with `df2["duration"] = pd.to_numeric(df2["duration"])`

Comment: I believe that would work, but now I've come across this:
ValueError: Unable to parse string "02:42.0" at position 2528

The dataframe has thousands of rows and after searching through it appears that some (Not sure how many) have this same issue.  I'd like to just get rid of the rows where the duration value has a ":" in it

Comment: I tried adding this before the "pd.to_numeric" function, and it has appeared to work:
pit = pit[~pit["duration"].str.contains(":")]

Comment: That should do it alright! It's not clear how many rows you'll lose as a result, but if you're happy I'm happy. It gets a bit tricky, but you could look into pd.Series.str.split if you wanted to try to clean the data rather than remove it. Don't forget to mark as answered if you're happy ;)

Comment: I have one other thing I need to do to get this perfect.  In addition to the mean function which you already explained (thanks by the way!) I wanted to have the numRed field have give me a value that represents the number of times that there was a red value for a specific instanceId for each raceId.  So for example in the post above instanceId 153 had a red value of 1 the first time it showed up for eventId 841 and then the second time it had a red value of 2.  I just want the numRed to show "2" when that gets merged down to 1 row.  So the duration is averaged, but numRed is just a count

Comment: You answered that one for yourself there ha! Just add this to your agg_dict: `"numRed": "count"`